# can't understand armv7 adr_l instruction example

Tags: assembly, armv7

This is an example code in https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0068/b/arm-instruction-reference/arm-pseudo-instructions/adrl-arm-pseudo-instruction

```
start   MOV     r0,#10
        ADRL    r4,start + 60000     ; => ADD r4,pc,#0xe800
                                     ;    ADD r4,r4,#0x254
```

I can't understand the comment in the code. Since 60000 is 0xea60. I think r4 should be pc + #0x2a60.  But the comment says (actually, emitted instruction) r4 becomes pc + #0xe800 + #0x254 = pc + 0xea54. (not #ea60). Why 12 less?

Comment: `MOV` takes up 4 bytes, and `pc` is already another 8 bytes ahead, giving 12 total.

Answer (score 4):

These are arm (i.e. arm32) instructions, even though your title and tag originally said arm64.  Note that the registers are `r0`, etc, instead of `x0` or `w0`.

On 32-bit ARM in non-Thumb (A32) state, the PC reads as the address of the current instruction plus 8.  (This is explained in the Architecture Reference Manual, E.1.2.3 in my copy of the Armv8-A version.)

So if `start` is at address 0x0, the `ADD r4,pc,#0xe800` instruction is at address 0x4, and so `pc` will be read as `0xc`.  Thus `ADD r4,pc,#0xe800` will load `r4` with `0xe80c`.  Then adding `0x254` will leave `r4` containing `0xea60` as desired.

arm64 is different.  There, the PC is not accessible as a general-purpose register, so you can't move to and from it directly, but instructions like `ADR` that act on it do treat it as pointing to the current instruction (without the 8 byte offset).